# How to set Form Checkbox to move with cell when row is resized?

Tags: vba, checkbox

I need to set a form checkbox in an Excel sheet row, to move with the row when the row heights in the sheet are reset.

I have tried various ideas I found, including .Placement = xlMoveAndSize

```
   Sub AddCheckBoxesRange()
   'https://www.contextures.com/excelcheckboxvba.html

   'by Dave Peterson
    'add Form checkboxes

    Dim c As Range
    Dim myCBX As CheckBox
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rngCB As Range
    Dim strCap As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim CB_Number As Integer

    Set wks = ActiveSheet      
    strCap = ""  'Caption

    For i = 4 To 6

        Set rngCB = wks.Range("C" & i)

        CB_Number = i - 3

        For Each c In rngCB

            With c
                 Set myCBX = wks.CHECKBOXES.Add _
                 (Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, _
                 Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
            End With

            With myCBX
                .Name = "cbx_" & c.Address(0, 0)
                .LinkedCell = c.Offset(0, 1) _
                .Address(external:=True)
                .Caption = strCap
                .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
                .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!CheckBox" & CB_Number             
            End With

        Next c

   Next i

   End Sub
```

I expect the checkboxes to move with the rows if the rows are resized.  If the rows start very high, and then are made lower, the checkboxes get left behind.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is that checkboxes do not support xlMoveAndSize - you can check that if you try to manually format it (option is greyed out) or debugging your code - even though you assign `xlMoveAndSize=1` the property stays at `xlMove=2`

Comment: My solution:  Add a Reset Sheet button.  Remove all the checkboxes, re-install them.

Comment: With only 4 checkboxes this looks like a decent solution. There are some other possible workarounds like a) use shapes instead of checkboxes - can handle xlMoveAndSize (still won't work well when the size is increased), but does not have LinkedCell property, so would require some more code to synchronize with cell value...

Comment: ... b) use worksheet events to recreate or (better) resize checkboxes. Still there is no event for resing rows/columns, so the built-in option would be to use one of Change/SelectionChange/Calculate events. The only option to make it work directly on row resize is to use some slippery tricks like volatile UDF with conditional formatting.

Comment: I have three workbooks with 22 sheets each, each sheet 20 - 33 checkboxes, and one difficult customer.  It will be either live with the row height, or reset the sheet, and re-click the checkboxes.  Tnx for your help.